# Why can access a site through browser, wheares write simple code to fetch, but get 403 error

Tags: javascript, python, http, https, request

**Endpoint:**  https://quizlet.com/webapi/3.2/images/search?query=hello&perPage=2

You guys can try to access this page as `Incognito`, from my side It works. So I think I can fetch data from that site.

I try to copy the request and run in Javascirpt, Python. However, It doesn't work. I got `403` error.

I also try to use `Burp Suite`. I can't access this site through Burp's browser.

Moreover, As I tried using `incognito` so I don't think it is relevant to cookies.

Code sample (**JS**):

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const response = await fetch(
  "https://quizlet.com/webapi/3.2/images/search?query=hello&perPage=2",
  {
    headers: {
      accept:
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "accept-language": "en",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      pragma: "no-cache",
      "sec-ch-ua":
        '"Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"',
      "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
      "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Linux"',
      "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
      "sec-fetch-site": "none",
      "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    },
    referrerPolicy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
    body: null,
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
  }
);

const data = await response.status;
console.log(data);
```

Code **Python**

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'quizlet.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en',
    'cookie': 'qi5=i2x3g7y1z9a6%3At3vMoQQig2yLcpN.HKWn; qtkn=7gT4DE7pN9URJ2AFDYeaVe; fs=qzkse0; app_session_id=9781a407-4f37-4c09-8e97-8156f182bb45; search_session=%7B%22search_session_id%22%3A%22-2379864199063990974614477b859794%22%2C%22query%22%3A%22overrated%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.1.1%22%2C%22platform%22%3A%22WEB%22%2C%22depth%22%3Anull%2C%22target_object_type%22%3A%22QImage%22%7D; __cf_bm=cB7hRf6JbcOFZ2kvQ3W12V4bxXiIgn_kF3n87RcI0h0-1631877048-0-Ac+Hi0pATLgW5N3JjqYa7uc5W4ZfDLOumvmCQixWJIKdcVj7stciFh8cYFVTOpr+q5pM2Q7LrXC/LsffOB6Mh2E=; __cfruid=81f16a673e6117331dd4270b3f4f29111590d7d8-1631877048',
}

params = (
    ('query', 'hello'),
    ('perPage', '2'),
)

response = requests.get(
    'https://quizlet.com/webapi/3.2/images/search', headers=headers, params=params)

# NB. Original query string below. It seems impossible to parse and
# reproduce query strings 100% accurately so the one below is given
# in case the reproduced version is not "correct".
# response = requests.get('https://quizlet.com/webapi/3.2/images/search?query=hello&perPage=2', headers=headers)


print(response.status_code)
```

Please help me out. I don't even know how can be that? (browser works, while code doesn't). Thank anyway.

Comment: Does that website have any cookies that store session info?

Comment: As I tried using `Incognito`. So I don't think it is relevant to cookies.

Comment: The response headers I see this resource returning includes `cf-` headers, which indicate that this is protected by Cloudflare.

Comment: Yes that's right. I faced to captcha. Is there anyway I pass through it?

Comment: Not sure this will help, but you could try to set the `user-agent` in your request

Comment: It seems not working

Comment: You can try using Selenium with some add-ons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the python side. I had a look out of interest, as I'm currently developing a REST API and was curious how they where securing it.

Using Wireshark it appears that the "requests" module in python does not handle http requests in the same manor as Chrome/Firefox, which I suspect they are using as a tell to give a captcha.

Anyway switching requests for the httpx module;

```
pip install httpx
```

https://www.python-httpx.org/

And changing the headers to replicate Firefox in full;

```
import httpx

headers = [

    ('Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'),
    ('Accept-Encoding','gzip, deflate, br'),
    ('Accept-Language','en-GB,en;q=0.5'),
    ('Cache-Control','max-age=0'),
    ('Connection','keep-alive'),
    ('Host','quizlet.com'),
    ('Sec-Fetch-Dest','document'),
    ('Sec-Fetch-Mode','navigate'),
    ('Sec-Fetch-Site','none'),
    ('Sec-Fetch-User','?1'),
    ('TE','trailers'),
    ('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests','1'),
    ('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0'),

]

params = (
    ('query', 'hello'),
    ('perPage', '2'),
)

response = httpx.get('https://quizlet.com/webapi/3.2/images/search', headers=headers, params=params,)

print(response.content)
```

Gives the following as appose to the captcha page for me;

```
{
    "responses": [{
        "models": {
            "image": [{
                "id": 18957872,
                "personId": 16641862,
                "timestamp": 1416579222,
                "lastModified": 1416579222,
                "code": "Gfg5XS88MRmYq8RS",
                "license": 1,
                "width": 480,
                "height": 360,
                "flickrId": null,
                "flickrOwner": null,
                "_legacyUrl": "http://o.quizlet.com/cZDE.6rHW7IrGptXSGm8FA.gif",
                "_legacyUrlSquare": "http://o.quizlet.com/cZDE.6rHW7IrGptXSGm8FA_s.gif",
                "_legacyUrlSmall": "http://o.quizlet.com/cZDE.6rHW7IrGptXSGm8FA_m.gif",
                "_secureLegacyUrl": "https://o.quizlet.com/cZDE.6rHW7IrGptXSGm8FA.gif",
                "_secureLegacyUrlLarge": "https://o.quizlet.com/cZDE.6rHW7IrGptXSGm8FA_b.gif",
                "_secureLegacyUrlSquare": "https://o.quizlet.com/cZDE.6rHW7IrGptXSGm8FA_s.gif",
                "_secureLegacyUrlSmall": "https://o.quizlet.com/cZDE.6rHW7IrGptXSGm8FA_m.gif"
            }, {
                "id": 9228314,
                "personId": 513525,
                "timestamp": 1406222781,
                "lastModified": 1406222781,
                "code": "bPHbzaV7KsGWfuXJ",
                "license": 1,
                "width": 298,
                "height": 232,
                "flickrId": null,
                "flickrOwner": null,
                "_legacyUrl": "http://o.quizlet.com/ptqCa7LsKjiVSBVPI3OfTA.jpg",
                "_legacyUrlSquare": "http://o.quizlet.com/ptqCa7LsKjiVSBVPI3OfTA_s.jpg",
                "_legacyUrlSmall": "http://o.quizlet.com/ptqCa7LsKjiVSBVPI3OfTA_m.jpg",
                "_secureLegacyUrl": "https://o.quizlet.com/ptqCa7LsKjiVSBVPI3OfTA.jpg",
                "_secureLegacyUrlLarge": "https://o.quizlet.com/ptqCa7LsKjiVSBVPI3OfTA_b.jpg",
                "_secureLegacyUrlSquare": "https://o.quizlet.com/ptqCa7LsKjiVSBVPI3OfTA_s.jpg",
                "_secureLegacyUrlSmall": "https://o.quizlet.com/ptqCa7LsKjiVSBVPI3OfTA_m.jpg"
            }]
        },
        "paging": {
            "total": 50,
            "page": 1,
            "perPage": 2,
            "token": "UuKKKAkmxv.r4YtwFDuRevZVGAHr"
        }
    }]
}
```